# How to disable macbook's mic, but not speakers?

Tags: audio, microphone

I found [this informative post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/21984663#21984663) about completely disabling audio on OS X by removing/disabling the required audio kernel extensions. The problem is this disables audio-in *and* audio-out, and I only want to disable audio-in.

I'm looking to completely disable audio-in, in a way which cannot be re-enabled by unprivileged users, not just muting it. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: So I'm guessing this is the expert advice: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/2016/06/22/why-has-mark-zuckerberg-taped-over-the-webcam-and-microphone-on/

Answer (score 1):

Insert a Minijack (headphones) in the Macbook's minijack input, option click on the Volume item in the Menu Bar and select use Audio Port for input:

[image]

Comment: Surely that can be undone by an unprivileged user...

Answer (score 0):

### Disabling Input

To disable the input, I'm not entirely sure.  Here's what I thought of:

- You can use a internal audio input device like SoundFlower, which basically routes the audio output into the audio input.
- You can mute the volume (although you said you don't want to do only that)
- You could take a look around the `/System/Library/Extensions/` folder and in the `IOAudioFamily.ktexts` file for anything useful, however that can muck up OS X.

### Preventing Changes

Disabling underprivileged users from changing the settings isn't actually too hard:

```
$ sudo chmod 700 /System.Library/PreferencePanes/Sound.prefPane
```

Will do the trick.  Loading the preference pane from any user (other than root) will display an error.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but the `chmod 700` command only prevents settings-changes using the graphical interface. Surely there are other programmatic ways to change it..

Comment: "surely"? Do you have an example of a non-privileged user changing a read-only file belonging to root?

Comment: @samh, no. What I meant is this only "locks" the GUI preference pane. Isn't there a way to enable/disable sound not using the GUI preference pane? Will changing the permissions on that file block that as well?

Answer (score 0):

chmod 700 still allows the current user to change sound prefs, chmod 000 would allow only root to change prefs.

```
$ sudo chmod 000 /System.Library/PreferencePanes/Sound.prefPane
```

Comment: This also prevents me from changing the prefs of `audio-out`...

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable the in built microphone in software in a hacker proof way.

Any software setting can be reverted.

Removing the kext will disable all audio, and an attacker with root access could replace the deleted kext.

The only way is to physically disconnect the microphone.

Despite an answer above, this causes no kernal panics or other issues. MacOS has no knowledge it is disconnected and simply sees audio with no sound.

I validated the above works on M1 Air with Monterey and M2 Pro running Ventura.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can just adjust the input volume to the lowest setting (it is a slider within system preferences => sound => input). Move it to the far left and leave the rest the same.

Be sure and select the correct device for sound input when making your adjustments.

Comment: That isn't what OP is looking for, "... not just muting it".  He wants to actually disable the input device entirely.